# YouTube Video Play-on-Load

Tags: jquery, function, video, gallery, squarespace

I running a Squarespace site and trying to get the YouTube video in a gallery to play-on-load feature using the `.click()` function with a delay. I can hear it in the background, but the window is not loading as it would if it was manually clicked.

Here is the site: http://www.sunsetstudiosent.com

Here is the current code I am running:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sqs-video-icon').delay(600).click();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `?autoplay=1` in the end of your youtube URL.

working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyLrrxhw/1/)

Comment: Did that already on the embed code inserted into the gallery. I think it is because the video is in the gallery and not a straight iframe. But good thought.

Comment: I saw your website again..the sound you are hearing is from a video on the third slide of your gallery actually. So one of them is playing on page load. I guess if you want help on the gallery itself then where the video loads on which slide it is, can you post your code for the gallery itself or put it in a fiddle.